# Stack snippet indentation - preview differs from result

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Today I encountered a code snippet whose preview renders fine during editing but with unwanted indentation after submitting:

```js
    arr1 = [{
    Title: "xXx: Return of Xander Cage",
    imdbRating: "5.5"
}]
```

To see what I am talking about, click on 'edit' below this question and compare the preview with what you see now.

Here is a screenshot of the preview of above snippet during editing:
[image]

Tested with Firefox 52 / Ubuntu.

Is this a bug and if yes, has it already been noticed by the SO team?